# Batch file for removing certain information in a line

Tags: batch-file

I have a gcode file .nc
What I want to do with a batch file is remove all line numbering i.e. N1 *N2 N3 etc. I also want to remove the M00 at the start. Do you have any idea on how to do this? I tried several codes but keep ending up with bad results. Any help much appreciated.

```
N1 G90 G54 G00 Z25. M00
*N2 (5MM CRB 4FL 16 LOC)
N3 T01 M06
N4 T02
N5 S12000 M03
N6 G54
N7 M08
N8 X125. Y100.
N9 Z2.5
N10 G01 Z-2.5 F822.96
N11 X125.25 F1645.92
N12 G03 X125. Y100.25 I-.25 J0 F3291.84
N13 X124.75 Y100. I0 J-.25
N14 X125. Y99.75 I.25 J0
N15 X125.25 Y100. I0 J.25
N16 G01 X127.25
N17 G03 X125. Y102.25 I-2.25 J0
N18 X122.75 Y100. I0 J-2.25
N19 X125. Y97.75 I2.25 J0
N20 X127.25 Y100. I0 J2.25
N21 G01 X129.25
N22 G03 X125. Y104.25 I-4.25 J0
N23 X120.75 Y100. I0 J-4.25
N24 X125. Y95.75 I4.25 J0
N25 X129.25 Y100. I0 J4.25
N26 G01 X131.25
N27 G03 X125. Y106.25 I-6.25 J0
N28 X118.75 Y100. I0 J-6.25
N29 X125. Y93.75 I6.25 J0
N30 X131.25 Y100. I0 J6.25
N31 G01 X133.25
N32 G03 X125. Y108.25 I-8.25 J0
N33 X116.75 Y100. I0 J-8.25
N34 X125. Y91.75 I8.25 J0
N35 X133.25 Y100. I0 J8.25
N36 G01 X135.25
N37 G03 X125. Y110.25 I-10.25 J0
```

Here is my attempt which only returns line numbers that I don't want:

```
H@echo off
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    rename test.nc test.tmp
    for /f %%a in (test.tmp) do (
        set foo=%%a
        if !foo!=="N" set foo=" "
        echo !foo! >> test.nc) 
del test.temp
```

Here is my finnished script for those who need it. Sorry about the norwegian text. The script just checks folder for .nc files. It only accepts one .nc file in the same folder as the script before runnning.

```
@echo off
    SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem stores date and time to variables
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
    set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
    set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
    set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
    set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
   
rem counting number of .nc files to a variable VAR
    for /f %%i in ('dir *.nc /s /b 2^> nul ^| find "" /v /c') do set VAR=%%i
    echo .nc file count %VAR%
rem checking if only one .nc file is the directory. Cancelling otherwise.   
    set n1=%VAR%
    set n2=1
        if %n1% lss %n2% (
            echo Mangler .nc fil
            pause
            exit /b
    ) else if %n1% gtr %n2% (
            echo For mange nc. filer i mappen. Kun tillatt med en .nc fil i mappen.
            pause
            exit /b
    ) else if %n1% equ %n2% (
            echo Ok. Riktig antall filer i mappen.
        )
        pause
rem removes first word/token from each line and also removes M00 unless there is only one word on the line (then it replaces it with M00=). Be aware!               
        for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ('type "*.nc"') do (
            set "remainder=%%j"
            echo !remainder:M00=! >> "%datestamp%-%timestamp%-scrubbed.nc"
            )
```

Comment: I understand. Well it is probably very easy, so my attempts are negligible. Here is my attempt, but it really only leaves what I wanted to delete:

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delims=` and `tokens=` to assign substrings to metavariables:
I used `filename.nc` as the demo file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ('type "filename.nc"') do (
     set "remainder=%%j"
     echo !remainder:M00=!
)
```

It might also be that you need to replace `. M00` instead of just `M00`. Do you do stop the program elsewhere in the G-Code other than line 1?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ('type "filename.nc"') do (
     set "remainder=%%j"
     echo !remainder:. M00=!
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. I now have this code working, copying only tokens 2 an so fort on to a new file. Only missing thing now is to remove M00.  ```@echo off  
    SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION  
     
 for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (test.nc) do (  
   set foo=%%b  
   echo !foo! >> test2.nc  
   )```

Comment: I show exactly how in my answer. See the  line `echo !remainder:M00=!` so in your case you need `echo !foo:M00=! >> test2.nc`

Comment: I got the code working alright now. However, I discovered that the  ```echo !remainder:M00=!```  writes M00= when a line already has only one token. Also, if there is an empty line it is deleted. I suppose that is ok though. You know how to prevent M00= to to be overwritten when there is only one item/token on the line to begin with?

Comment: wait. Which variable are you useing in your script? `remainder` or `foo`?

Comment: I tried using foo at an earlier stage, but the finished script only uses remainder.

Comment: @OP: replace `echo !remainder:M00=!...` with `if defined remainder echo !remainder:M00=!...` so that the `echo` will not be executed if there is only 1 token in the line.